# What should I change here in order to get the following SQL code working?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Hello StackOverflow community.
I'm having the following error when I execute this SQL query:
I created all this code in order to create some tables and VisualStudio code doesn't show me any syntax error. What should I change here?

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ')

GO
CREATE TABLE SECCIO (
    seccio_codi INT(10) PRIMARY KEY,
    seccio' at line 10
```

This is my SQL code:
Maybe it is a comma or something else, but I'm not able to find what is the real issue here as everything seems okey.

```
CREATE TABLE SOCI (
    soci_nif VARCHAR(9) PRIMARY KEY,
    soci_nom VARCHAR(15),
    soci_cog1 VARCHAR(15),
    soci_cog2 VARCHAR(15),
    soci_adreca VARCHAR(30),
    soci_codipostal INT(5),
    soci_poblacio VARCHAR(15),
    soci_telefon INT(9) UNIQUE,
)
GO
CREATE TABLE REBUT (
    numero_rebut INT(20) PRIMARY KEY,
    soci_nif INT(15) UNIQUE,
    data_rebut DATE DEFAULT GETDATE, 
    estat_rebut VARCHAR(7), CHECK (estat_rebut IN('pagat','pendent','rebut')),
    importe INT(9) CHECK (importe > 0),
    CONSTRAINT fk_numero_rebut FOREIGN KEY (soci_nif) REFERENCES SOCI(soci_nif)
)
GO
CREATE TABLE SECCIO (
    seccio_codi INT(10) PRIMARY KEY,
    seccio_nom VARCHAR(20) UNIQUE,
    seccio_telefon INT(9) UNIQUE,
    seccio_fax INT(9) UNIQUE,
    seccio_e_mail VARCHAR(20) UNIQUE,
    junta_nif VARCHAR(9) UNIQUE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_junta_nif FOREIGN KEY (junta_nif) REFERENCES JUNTA(junta_nif)
)
GO
CREATE TABLE JUNTA (
    junta_nif VARCHAR(9) PRIMARY KEY,
    junta_nom VARCHAR(10) UNIQUE,
    junta_cog1 VARCHAR(15),
    junta_cog2 VARCHAR(15),
    junta_adreca VARCHAR(30),
    junta_codi_postal INT(5),
    junta_poblacio VARCHAR(10),
    junta_telefon INT(9) UNIQUE,
    junta_mobil INT(9) UNIQUE
)
GO
CREATE TABLE EQUIP (
    equip_codi VARCHAR(4) PRIMARY KEY,
    equip_nom VARCHAR(9),
    equip_patrocinador VARCHAR(9),
    seccio_codi INT(5) UNIQUE,
    categoria_codi INT(4) UNIQUE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_seccio_codi FOREIGN KEY (seccio_codi) REFERENCES SECCIO(seccio_codi),
    CONSTRAINT fk_categoria_codi FOREIGN KEY (categoria_codi) REFERENCES CATEGORIA(categoria_codi)
)
GO
CREATE TABLE CATEGORIA(
    categoria_codi INT(4) PRIMARY KEY,
    nom_categoria VARCHAR(10)
)
GO
CREATE TABLE JUGADOR (
    jug_id VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY,
    jugador_nom VARCHAR(10),
    jug_cog1 VARCHAR(15),
    jug_cog2 VARCHAR(15),
    jug_data_naixament DATE,
    equip_codi VARCHAR(4),
    CONSTRAINT fk_equip_codi FOREIGN KEY (equip_codi) REFERENCES EQUIP(equip_codi)
)
GO
CREATE TABLE NACIONALITAT(
    nac_sigles_id INT(4) PRIMARY KEY,
    nac_nom VARCHAR(3)
)
GO
CREATE TABLE NACIONALITATS_JUGADORS(
    jug_identificador VARCHAR(5) PRIMARY KEY,
    nacis_sigles_id VARCHAR(3) PRIMARY KEY,
    data_nacionalitat DATA,
    CONSTRAINT fk_jug_identificador FOREIGN KEY (jug_identificador) REFERENCES JUGADOR(jug_id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_nacis_sigles_id FOREIGN KEY (nacis_sigles_id) REFERENCES NACIONALITAT(nac_sigles_id)
)
GO
CREATE TABLE ENTRENADOR(
    entrenador_id VARCHAR(5) PRIMARY KEY,
    entrenador_nom VARCHAR(10),
    entrenador_cognoms VARCHAR(15)
)
GO
CREATE TABLE ABONATS(
    soci_nif VARCHAR(9) PRIMARY KEY,
    seccio_codi INT(10) PRIMARY KEY,
    data_soci_seccio DATE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_soci_nif FOREIGN KEY (soci_nif) REFERENCES SOCI(soci_nif),
    CONSTRAINT fk_seccio_codi FOREIGN KEY (seccio_codi) REFERENCES SECCIO(soccio_codi)
)
GO
CREATE TABLE TASCA_ENTRENADOR (
    entrenador_id VARCHAR(5) PRIMARY KEY,
    equip_codi VARCHAR(4) PRIMARY KEY,
    tasca VARCHAR(30),
    data_inici_tasca DATE DEFAULT GETDATE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_entrenador_id FOREIGN KEY (entrenador_id) REFERENCES ENTRENADOR(entrenador_id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_equip_codi FOREIGN KEY (equip_codi) REFERENCES EQUIP(equip_codi)
)
```

Thanks in advance for the help!!

Comment: I am guessing that the issue is `GO`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff The same error happens when I remove go.

Comment: What is soci_telefon?

Comment: @Strawberry It is a field inside 'SOCI' table, an integer of 9 that must not be repeated. English translation of the field would be "partner telephone"

Comment: It's true that telephone numbers are composed of integers, but it's rare that you would want to perform an arithmetic operation on them. In this sense, they are in fact strings, and should be stored as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have in your first Create table at the end a comma too much so change it to

then you have too many errors in your code to explai.
Foreign keys have to have a unique name.

Referenced Table and column reference must have the same Datatype

Datatype Data doesn't exist so i put there data_nacionalitat varchar(50)

Last but nit Least Go between is SQL Server, and doesn't work in mysql also all cretes have to have a semikolo9n at the end

> ```
> CREATE TABLE SOCI (
>     soci_nif VARCHAR(9) PRIMARY KEY,
>     soci_nom VARCHAR(15),
>     soci_cog1 VARCHAR(15),
>     soci_cog2 VARCHAR(15),
>     soci_adreca VARCHAR(30),
>     soci_codipostal INT(5),
>     soci_poblacio VARCHAR(15),
>     soci_telefon INT(9) UNIQUE
> );
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE REBUT (
>     numero_rebut INT(20) PRIMARY KEY,
>     soci_nif VARCHAR(9) UNIQUE,
>     data_rebut DATE , 
>     estat_rebut VARCHAR(7), CHECK (estat_rebut IN('pagat','pendent','rebut')),
>     importe INT(9) CHECK (importe > 0),
>     CONSTRAINT fk_numero_rebut FOREIGN KEY (soci_nif) REFERENCES SOCI(soci_nif)
> );
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE JUNTA (
>     junta_nif VARCHAR(9) PRIMARY KEY,
>     junta_nom VARCHAR(10) UNIQUE,
>     junta_cog1 VARCHAR(15),
>     junta_cog2 VARCHAR(15),
>     junta_adreca VARCHAR(30),
>     junta_codi_postal INT(5),
>     junta_poblacio VARCHAR(10),
>     junta_telefon INT(9) UNIQUE,
>     junta_mobil INT(9) UNIQUE
> );
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE SECCIO (
>     seccio_codi INT(10) PRIMARY KEY,
>     seccio_nom VARCHAR(20) UNIQUE,
>     seccio_telefon INT(9) UNIQUE,
>     seccio_fax INT(9) UNIQUE,
>     seccio_e_mail VARCHAR(20) UNIQUE,
>     junta_nif VARCHAR(9) UNIQUE,
>     CONSTRAINT fk_junta_nif FOREIGN KEY (junta_nif) REFERENCES JUNTA(junta_nif)
> );
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE CATEGORIA(
>     categoria_codi INT(4) PRIMARY KEY,
>     nom_categoria VARCHAR(10)
> );
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE EQUIP (
>     equip_codi VARCHAR(4) PRIMARY KEY,
>     equip_nom VARCHAR(9),
>     equip_patrocinador VARCHAR(9),
>     seccio_codi INT(10) UNIQUE,
>     categoria_codi INT(4) UNIQUE,
>     CONSTRAINT fk_seccio_codi FOREIGN KEY (seccio_codi) REFERENCES SECCIO(seccio_codi),
>     CONSTRAINT fk_categoria_codi FOREIGN KEY (categoria_codi) REFERENCES CATEGORIA(categoria_codi)
> );
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE JUGADOR (
>     jug_id VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY,
>     jugador_nom VARCHAR(10),
>     jug_cog1 VARCHAR(15),
>     jug_cog2 VARCHAR(15),
>     jug_data_naixament DATE,
>     equip_codi VARCHAR(4),
>     CONSTRAINT fk_equip_codi FOREIGN KEY (equip_codi) REFERENCES EQUIP(equip_codi)
> );
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE NACIONALITAT(
>     nac_sigles_id INT(4) PRIMARY KEY,
>     nac_nom VARCHAR(3)
> );
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE NACIONALITATS_JUGADORS(
>     jug_identificador VARCHAR(20) ,
>     nacis_sigles_id INT(4) ,
>     data_nacionalitat varchar(50),
>     PRIMARY KEY (jug_identificador, nacis_sigles_id),
>     CONSTRAINT fk_jug_identificador FOREIGN KEY (jug_identificador) REFERENCES JUGADOR(jug_id),
>     CONSTRAINT fk_nacis_sigles_id FOREIGN KEY (nacis_sigles_id) REFERENCES NACIONALITAT(nac_sigles_id)
> );
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE ENTRENADOR(
>     entrenador_id VARCHAR(5) PRIMARY KEY,
>     entrenador_nom VARCHAR(10),
>     entrenador_cognoms VARCHAR(15)
> );
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE ABONATS(
>     soci_nif VARCHAR(9) ,
>     seccio_codi INT(10) ,
>     data_soci_seccio DATE,
>     PRIMARY KEY (soci_nif, seccio_codi),
>     CONSTRAINT fk_soci_nif FOREIGN KEY (soci_nif) REFERENCES SOCI(soci_nif),
>     CONSTRAINT fk_seccio_codi2 FOREIGN KEY (seccio_codi) REFERENCES SECCIO(seccio_codi)
> );
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE TASCA_ENTRENADOR (
>     entrenador_id VARCHAR(5) ,
>     equip_codi VARCHAR(4) ,
>     tasca VARCHAR(30),
>     data_inici_tasca DATE ,
>     PRIMARY KEY (entrenador_id, equip_codi),
>     CONSTRAINT fk_entrenador_id FOREIGN KEY (entrenador_id) REFERENCES ENTRENADOR(entrenador_id),
>     CONSTRAINT fk_equip_codi2 FOREIGN KEY (equip_codi) REFERENCES EQUIP(equip_codi)
> );
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=07d20d093cae32e049d6602a2d5bf819)*

Comment: "a comma too much" what do you mean? Should I remove, add a comma or what?

Comment: look at my post  there you see  soci_telefon INT(9) UNIQUE
)  no comma after the UNIQUE

Comment: Even if I do that I still having the error. In fact, PHPMYADMIN mark this as an additional mistake.

Comment: So i had to change almiost the hole structure to get running, and you can see in the dbfiddle example now it works.

Comment: Thank you very much @nbk!! Really appreciate the help (: